# How can I remove default button class of a dataTables button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using Data table with Button. I want to show Success button rather default.
I tried this Code

```
buttons: [
{
extend: "excel",
className: "btn-sm btn-success",
titleAttr: 'Export in Excel',
text: 'Excel'
}]
```

This code is working but this is adding btn-success class, But I want to remove the btn-default class first and then add the success class.

Current Classes: `"btn btn-default buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn-sm btn-success"`

What I want : `"btn buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn-sm btn-success"`

Comment: We will need to know which library you are using.

Comment: In jquery `$('#your_button_id').removeClass('btn-default');`

Comment: I am Using DataTables 1.10.11 library and jquery-2.2.3

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `button.button.className` ? https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.className. This is the default behavior.  *... any classes you set will automatically be appended to the extended button's class. It will not overwrite the original class.*. What is the problem with that ?

Comment: @DavidDomain that you would like to remove the default classes...?

Comment: @davidkonrad I was just asking, because in the case of `btn-default` and `btn-success` it is not really necessary to remove the class according to [cascading order](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#cascading-order). Anyway, there is actually the `buttons.dom.button` option to control the tag type and class name. I posted an answer.

Comment: @DavidDomain
The issue with leaving the other class is that it may wind up overriding the class.

For example, I'm using bootstrap 4; it adds btn-secondary by default to the buttons.  If I create a button with btn-primary, my class gets overriden (because in the bootstrap css, btn-primary comes before btn-secondary)

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/charleycartee/aep2qfz5/13/

Note that the first button shows up as the btn-secondary grey rather than the btn-primary blue (it has both classes)

Comment: Currently I'm solving it with a bit of javascript in the page
$(".btn-secondary.btn-primary").removeClass("btn-secondary")

That's kind of hacky though

Comment: @charley Just like i said in the comment above, i posted an answer. Just use the `buttons.dom.button` prop, which will give you total control over the tag and class-name creation. No need to do any JS hacks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, this can be really annoying. It is the same without using bootstrap, where `.dt-button` always is added even if you declare `className`. There is a [**`init`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.init) callback you can use to modify for example classes :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: "excel",
    className: "btn-sm btn-success",
    titleAttr: 'Export in Excel',
    text: 'Excel',
    init: function(api, node, config) {
       $(node).removeClass('btn-default')
    }
  }]
});
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/m6hysypd/**

---

**Update**: Have received a lot of upvotes on this, but the **correct** or **best**
 answer is actually "DavidDomains"'s answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313764/1407478). Use

```js
buttons: {
  dom: {
    button: {
      className: ''
    }
  },
  buttons: [{
    //here comes your button definitions
  }]
}
```

Comment: Yes, It Worked For me...:)

Comment: @ansh
I have worked out/found a MUCH Better solution now



demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/aep2qfz5/22/
From: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51001

Answer (score 42):

You should take a look at the `buttons.dom.button` option.

> [**buttons.dom.button**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.dom.button)
>
> *This option controls the HTML tag that is used to create each individual button. With this option the tag type and class name can be specified using the tag and className properties of this object.*

This will give you total control on how the button will be rendered in the DOM. No need to remove any classes afterwards.

Here is an example.

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: {
    dom: {
      button: {
        tag: 'button',
        className: ''
      }
    },
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'excel',
      className: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
      titleAttr: 'Excel export.',
      text: 'Excel',
      filename: 'excel-export',
      extension: '.xlsx'
    }, {
      extend: 'copy',
      className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
      titleAttr: 'Copy table data.',
      text: 'Copy'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jszip-3.1.3/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jszip-3.1.3/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

Changing the default class for all buttons in Datatable 
(Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gte8zxbs/))

```
$.fn.dataTable.Buttons.defaults.dom.button.className = 'btn'; //'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.dt-button').removeClass("dt-button");
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help

```
$('.dt-button').attr("class","btn-success");
```

Add this to jquery after loading Datatables

Or you can make your own css class and mark the require attributes as !important to override the default style

Comment: is your using jquery, don't use attr to modify classes.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to hide Excel text on button:

```
 extend: 'excel',

 text: '',

 className: "btn btn-info btn-sm  glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt",
```